# К шапке сайта надо подключить поиск

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть следующий код:

```js
window.onscroll = function showHeader() {
    var header = document.querySelector('.header');
    if(window.pageYOffset > 50){
        header.classList.add('header_fixed');
    } else{
        header.classList.remove('header_fixed');
    }
}
```

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 92%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-block{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background: #006091;
}

.header-inner{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.header_fixed{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    animation-name: showHeader;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes showHeader{
    0%
    {
        top: -70px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100%
    {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.logo{
    width: 210px;
    height: 75px;
    background: url(../images/Logo.png);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}

.logo a{
 z-index: 100;
 width: 210px;
    height: 75px;
}



.nav{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-link{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}

.nav-link a:hover {
 transition: all .2s ease;
  color: #f2b46d;
}

.down, .up{
 font-size: 13px;
}

.submenu{
   width: 685px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    background: #888;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: none;
}

.submenu ul li {
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.submenu ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 135px;
    height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
 <div class="header-block">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header-inner">
   <a href="#">
   <div class="logo">
   </div>
   </a>
    <nav class="nav">
     <ul class="menu">
     <li class="nav-link"><a href="/images/page/a1.jpg">Абитуриенту
      <span class="down"> &#9660;</span>
      <span class="up"> &#9650;</span></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="#">Перечень необходимых документов</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-link"><a href="/images/page/01.jpg">Обучение
       <span class="down"> &#9660;</span>
      <span class="up"> &#9650;</span></a>
     <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="#">Бакалавриат</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Колледж</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Курсы</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-link"><a href="/images/page/n1.jpg">Новости</a></li>
     <li class="nav-link"><a href="/images/page/o1.jpg">О нас</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Так вот на эту шапку нужно подключить поиск по сайту, с небольшим отступом от текста(около 20px), ну вот никак не получается, либо он вниз скатывается, либо еще куда. И заранее извиняюсь, если у вас кровь из глазу от такого кода, только 3 дня назад начал учиться верстать сайты. Конечный результат должен быть таким:
[image: Конечный результат должен быть таким]

Comment: Покажите какого результата хотите добиться. Поиск по сайту - это `input`. Вы же имеете ввиду меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто добавить в таком виде:

```
         <div class="searh">
            <input type="text" placeholder="поиск" name="">
         </div>
```

Сразу за закрывающим тегом /nav, то получится искомый результат, дальше играйтесь центровкой и padding/margin для достижения требуемых отступов[image: пример внешнего вида]